# How to get All JSON object from local JSON file in React functional component?

Tags: json, reactjs, redux, react-functional-component

I'm using functional component and I'm getting JSOS object from local file And in component I'm setting that JSON in some state.

After that few object I spliced(deleted) from  that setState. But again in onchange function I want all the JSON object but here I'm getting updated json means few are deleted, Is there any method I can store all JSON object in some place? can anybody help me in this.

```
const StudyDetails = () => {

  const [supplyPlan, setSupplyPlan] = useState([]);
  
    
     const getSupplyPlanDetails = useCallback(
    async () => {
    
      try {
        const payload = {
          studyName:  studyDetails?.studyName
          ? studyDetails?.studyName
          : query.get("name"),
          country: [],
          depot: [],
          material: [],
          site: [],
          inTransientMaterial,
       
        };
        const res = await getSupplyPlan(payload);
       //setSupplyPlan(res);
       console.log(res)
      // setSupplyPlan(supplyData)
         
      } catch (err) {
        setSupplyPlan([]);
      }
    },
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
    []
  );
  
    useEffect(() => {
    getSupplyPlanDetails();
  }, [ getSupplyPlanDetails]);
  
   const onChange = (e) => {debugger
   console.log(supplyData)
   }
    return (
      <div>
       <Checkbox

                        onChange={onChange}
                      >
                        In Transit
                      </Checkbox>
          {supplyPlan?.map((item, index) => (
                    <Fragment key={index}>
                      <SupplyChain item={item}  />
                      <Divider className="supply-chain-divider" />
                    </Fragment>
                  ))}
      </div>
    )
}
```

I'm splicing few object in supplyChain component:

```
const SupplyChain = ({ item }) => {
 
   useEffect(() => {
    let data = [];
    if (item && item.inTransit.length != 1) {
      item &&
        item.inTransit &&
        item.inTransit.length > 0 &&
        item.inTransit.map((intrans, index) => {
          if (
            intrans.from === item.depots?.packagingDepot?.[0]?.depotName &&
            intrans.to === "sites"
          ) {
            let directPath = item.inTransit.splice(index, 1);
            setDirectSite(directPath);
            
          }
       
          setFilterJson(item.inTransit);
          // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
          item = { ...item, filterJson: item.inTransit };
        });
    }
}
```

So if again when I click on onchange function I want all objects of JSON.

please someone help me in this

Comment: Share your code please

Comment: Cant you store the original json response in a separate state variable and use it?